# What does python "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in scalar negative" mean?

Tags: python-3.x

what would cause a RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in scalar negative.  I searched and can't find what a scalar negative overflow is.

I randomly receive this warning in my code and have captured it in the code example below.  However, if I run the code independenly with the same inputs it does not throw the warning   for example I have seen the error thrown with

num_available = 112
requested_num = 85
this would return a none and throw the exception.

```
try:
   filled = -min(num_available, abs(requested_num))
except RuntimeWarning as e:
   print(f'There was a RuntimeWarning in items filled: {e}')
```

I'm running on windows 10 and python 3.10

Comment: Can you please show a [mre]? The code you have shown assigns -85 to `filled` but does not raise a `RuntimeWarning`.

Comment: Are you using numpy in this code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is being caused by numpy.  Sometimes num_available or requested_num being cast as uint32.  When the uint32 was passed into the equation and and I negated it, it would throw the exception.

here is a way to reproduce the error

```
import numpy as np
x = np.uint32(54)
print(type(x))
print(-x)
```

There is a couple ways to solve this.  This can be cast into a python native int or float

```
y = x.item()
print(type(y))
print(y)

z = float(x)
print(type(z))
print(z)
```

or can use numpy and recast as an int

```
recastX = np.int32(x)
print(type(recastX))
print(recastX)
```